# Python: Get resolution of videos from streaming links

Tags: python, video-streaming, resolution

I am pretty new to Python. I am currently using version 3.3.2. I have an array of links to sources of streaming videos. What I want to do is sort them between HD(>720p) and non-HD(<720p) videos. I have been searching the internet, but the only closest I got to was a ffmpeg python wrapper https://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/.

So I wanted to know if it is even possible? If yes, can you please link me to some resources, or what keywords I should be searching on google?

Regards

Comment: Are you planning to download them? Are these actual streaming links (whether Flash RTMP, Silverlight, or something else), HTML5 pseudo-streaming, or just plain download links? Can you be sure that the container and codec formats will be in some restricted set (e.g., the set defined by HTML5), or do you need to handle everything in the word?

Comment: I want the user to be able to search for a video on different websites (dailymotion, metacafe, youtube,... ), but I only want to give him the links that have the HD version available. So I was hoping to get the max available video resolution and check on that.

Comment: Some of those sites have Flash streaming, and if you want to handle that, you're either going to need to drive a Flash plugin, or write custom code to parse the parameters that the web page passes to the SWF (which works differently on every site… and sometimes isn't even possible). And often, there is no way to tell what the format is going to be until you start downloading it. So, there are two parts to this: (1) a universal web video downloader, and (2) detecting the format of a downloaded video. You're asking for (2), the easy part, which is not answerable until you do (1), the hard part.

Comment: Alternatively, at least some of those sites have web service APIs, which let you search and retrieve metadata on a video _without_ downloading it. For example, see the [YouTube developer page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/). That will make your life a whole lot easier—except that you'll have to write different code for every site you care about. Is that the way you want to go?

Comment: Thanks. That really helped me setting my direction. I will consider this question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to use the web service API for each site.

For example, the [`YouTube` API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) lets you issue a search and get back metadata on all of the matching videos. If you look at the [video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), properties, you can check `definition == 'hd'`, or you can iterate the `videoStreams` for the video and check whether `heightPixels >= 720` or `bitrateBps >= 8*1024*1024` or whatever you think is an appropriate definition for "HD" if you don't like theirs.

You can find the APIs for most sites by just googling "Foo API", but here are links for the ones you asked about:

- [Daily Motion](http://www.dailymotion.com/developer)
- Metacafe: I can't find the API docs anymore, but it's just simple RSS feeds.
- [YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

The hard way to do this is to write a universal video downloader—which is very, very hard—and process the file with something like `pyffmpeg` after you download it (or, if you're lucky, after you've only downloaded part of it).